# AWS Mysfits - Invalid HTTP Endpoint API Gateway Push

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway

On Module 4 of the AWS Mythical Mysfits tutorial and I am unable to push the API changes after updating the swagger doc with all of the replace mes. I have followed the instructions for this section three times.

REF: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-modern-app-fargate-lambda-dynamodb-python/module-four/

I am running the following command through Cloud9:

```
aws apigateway import-rest-api --parameters endpointConfigurationTypes=REGIONAL --body file://~/environment/aws-modern-application-workshop/module-4/aws-cli/api-swagger.json --fail-on-warnings
```

With the api-swagger-json:

```
{
    "swagger": 2.0,
    "info": {
        "title": "MysfitsApi"
    },
    "securityDefinitions": {
        "MysfitsUserPoolAuthorizer": {
            "type": "apiKey",
            "name": "Authorization",
            "in": "header",
            "x-amazon-apigateway-authtype": "cognito_user_pools",
            "x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer": {
                "type": "COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
                "providerARNs": [
                    "arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-2:730082756200:userpool/us-east-2_jFYjOTZRU"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "paths": {
        "/": {
            "get": {
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Default response for CORS method",
                        "headers": {
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                    "connectionType": "VPC_LINK",
                    "responses": {
                        "default": {
                            "statusCode": "200",
                            "responseParameters": {
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "connectionId": "wg0305",
                    "httpMethod": "GET",
                    "type": "HTTP_PROXY",
                    "uri": "mysfits-nlb-52741b4979bb0b50.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
                }
            },
            "options": {
                "summary": "CORS support",
                "description": "Enable CORS by returning correct headers\n",
                "consumes": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "produces": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "tags": [
                    "CORS"
                ],
                "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                    "type": "mock",
                    "requestTemplates": {
                        "application/json": "{\n  \"statusCode\" : 200\n}\n"
                    },
                    "responses": {
                        "default": {
                            "statusCode": "200",
                            "responseParameters": {
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
                            },
                            "responseTemplates": {
                                "application/json": "{}\n"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Default response for CORS method",
                        "headers": {
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/mysfits": {
            "get": {
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Default response for CORS method",
                        "headers": {
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                    "connectionType": "VPC_LINK",
                    "connectionId": "wg0305",
                    "httpMethod": "GET",
                    "type": "HTTP_PROXY",
                    "uri": "http://mysfits-nlb-52741b4979bb0b50.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mysfits",
                    "responses": {
                        "default": {
                            "statusCode": "200",
                            "responseParameters": {
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "options": {
                "summary": "CORS support",
                "description": "Enable CORS by returning correct headers\n",
                "consumes": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "produces": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "tags": [
                    "CORS"
                ],
                "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                    "type": "mock",
                    "requestTemplates": {
                        "application/json": "{\n  \"statusCode\" : 200\n}\n"
                    },
                    "responses": {
                        "default": {
                            "statusCode": "200",
                            "responseParameters": {
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
                            },
                            "responseTemplates": {
                                "application/json": "{}\n"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Default response for CORS method",
                        "headers": {
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/mysfits/{mysfitId}": {
            "get": {
                "parameters": [{
                    "name": "mysfitId",
                    "in": "path",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string"
                }],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Default response for CORS method",
                        "headers": {
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                    "requestParameters": {
                        "integration.request.path.mysfitId": "method.request.path.mysfitId"
                    },
                    "connectionType": "VPC_LINK",
                    "connectionId": "wg0305",
                    "httpMethod": "GET",
                    "type": "HTTP_PROXY",
                    "uri": "http://mysfits-nlb-52741b4979bb0b50.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mysfits/{mysfitId}",
                    "responses": {
                        "default": {
                            "statusCode": "200",
                            "responseParameters": {
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "options": {
                "summary": "CORS support",
                "description": "Enable CORS by returning correct headers\n",
                "consumes": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "produces": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "tags": [
                    "CORS"
                ],
                "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                    "type": "mock",
                    "requestTemplates": {
                        "application/json": "{\n  \"statusCode\" : 200\n}\n"
                    },
                    "responses": {
                        "default": {
                            "statusCode": "200",
                            "responseParameters": {
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
                            },
                            "responseTemplates": {
                                "application/json": "{}\n"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Default response for CORS method",
                        "headers": {
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/mysfits/{mysfitId}/adopt": {
            "post": {
                "parameters": [{
                    "name": "mysfitId",
                    "in": "path",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string"
                }],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Default response for CORS method",
                        "headers": {
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "security": [{
                    "MysfitsUserPoolAuthorizer": [

                    ]
                }],
                "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                    "requestParameters": {
                        "integration.request.path.mysfitId": "method.request.path.mysfitId"
                    },
                    "connectionType": "VPC_LINK",
                    "connectionId": "wg0305",
                    "httpMethod": "POST",
                    "type": "HTTP_PROXY",
                    "uri": "http://mysfits-nlb-52741b4979bb0b50.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mysfits/{mysfitId}/adopt",
                    "responses": {
                        "default": {
                            "statusCode": "200",
                            "responseParameters": {
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "options": {
                "summary": "CORS support",
                "description": "Enable CORS by returning correct headers\n",
                "consumes": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "produces": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "tags": [
                    "CORS"
                ],
                "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                    "type": "mock",
                    "requestTemplates": {
                        "application/json": "{\n  \"statusCode\" : 200\n}\n"
                    },
                    "responses": {
                        "default": {
                            "statusCode": "200",
                            "responseParameters": {
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
                            },
                            "responseTemplates": {
                                "application/json": "{}\n"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Default response for CORS method",
                        "headers": {
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/mysfits/{mysfitId}/like": {
            "post": {
                "parameters": [{
                    "name": "mysfitId",
                    "in": "path",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string"
                }],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Default response for CORS method",
                        "headers": {
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "security": [{
                    "MysfitsUserPoolAuthorizer": [

                    ]
                }],
                "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                    "responses": {
                        "default": {
                            "statusCode": "200",
                            "responseParameters": {
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "requestParameters": {
                        "integration.request.path.mysfitId": "method.request.path.mysfitId"
                    },
                    "connectionType": "VPC_LINK",
                    "connectionId": "wg0305",
                    "httpMethod": "POST",
                    "security": [{
                        "MysfitsUserPoolAuthorizer": [

                        ]
                    }],
                    "type": "HTTP_PROXY",
                    "uri": "http://mysfits-nlb-52741b4979bb0b50.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mysfits/{mysfitId}/like",
                    "responses": {
                        "default": {
                            "statusCode": "200",
                            "responseParameters": {
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "options": {
                "summary": "CORS support",
                "description": "Enable CORS by returning correct headers\n",
                "consumes": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "produces": [
                    "application/json"
                ],
                "tags": [
                    "CORS"
                ],
                "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                    "type": "mock",
                    "requestTemplates": {
                        "application/json": "{\n  \"statusCode\" : 200\n}\n"
                    },
                    "responses": {
                        "default": {
                            "statusCode": "200",
                            "responseParameters": {
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "'*'",
                                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
                            },
                            "responseTemplates": {
                                "application/json": "{}\n"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Default response for CORS method",
                        "headers": {
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I receive the error:

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the ImportRestApi operation: Errors found during import:
        Unable to put integration on 'GET' for resource at path '/': Invalid HTTP endpoint specified for URI
```

Where am I going wrong? Which URI is invalid? How can I add more error catching to see the line where it ran into this exception and the exception message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your swagger file is malformed. It is giving an error "duplicated mapping key" when validated. I think you have defined the "responses" twice.

Comment: Have you sorted this out

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Quite simply, URI in '/' should be `http://mysfits-nlb-52741b4979bb0b50.elb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com`